# Combine multiple select * queries for tables with a different number of columns/names for export into a different database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables which have multiple number of columns and field names. I want to select * data from these tables where there is a specific condition(then insert the data into a different database). For example, if I run below queries separately, each of them returns a different number of rows where number of columns and field's names are totally different. Of course I can export the results of below queries separately in three different files and then insert them into a different database, but my goal is to combine these results so that I can export the data in one file.

```
Select * From table1 Where id>=500;
Select * From table2 Where id>=200;
Select * From table3 Where id>=1500;
```

Please note that `Union all` did not work in this case and MySQL said `#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`.

Could you please let me know if you can help on this problem?

Comment: Are you going to import that data into one table or three tables in your target database?

Comment: @WojtusJ, In three tables,

Comment: ... and on what operating system are you performing your export, also what tool are you using?

Comment: If you have three source tables and three target tables why do you want to export it in one file?

Comment: @WojtusJ, thanks for you help, I use Mac and PhPMyAdmin,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going wrong way, if you axport a union, than you will have problem importing that. Instead try to merge files, or export three tables separatly into one file, for example using tool **MYSQLDUMP** like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -pyour_password your_database table1 >> /tmp/mysql_dump.sql
mysqldump -u root -pyour_password your_database table2 >> /tmp/mysql_dump.sql
mysqldump -u root -pyour_password your_database table3 >> /tmp/mysql_dump.sql
```

EDIT:
You stated that you need a where condition - that is also possible, like that:

```
mysqldump -u root -pyour_password --where="id>=500" your_database table1 >> /tmp/mysql_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Select 
      ID as ID,
      '' as Name,
      '' as Something 
From table1 
where id>=500;

union all

Select 
     ID as ID, 
     Name as Name, 
     '' as Something 
from table2 
where id>=200;

union all

Select 
     ID as ID,
     '' as Name, 
     Something as Something 
 from table3 
 where id>=1500;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have TableA with columns col1 and col2, and TableB with col3 and col for you do a union with the following:

```
Select col1,col2,col3=null,col4=null from TableA
Union all
Select col1=null,col2=null,col3,col4 from TableB
```

That will make the union statement work and allow you to export the data.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your approach creates a different table structure

Comment: So then it seems you want to take three tables with different structures, dump them to a single file so in order to import those same three tables into another database from the single file.  This is impossible. If you want to keep the same table structure, use @WojtusJ answer above